# Estimating the length of the side of the triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, inequality, triangles

I posted this problem a few days back, but forgot to include a key information, which meant it was a meaningless question. I hope it makes sense now and someone could give me a hand with this.

> It is given, that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2N}$ for $N \geq 2$ a natural number, which also makes an oriented angle of $45^{\circ}$ with vertical axis and the height from the bottom of the triangle to the top is $\epsilon$. 
>   I need to estimate the length of the side $A$ in terms of $N$ and $\epsilon$, as far as I know the estimate $A \leq \frac{8\epsilon}{N} $ should hold but I am really having issues showing it.

In particular having the estimate involving $N$, when using simple trigonometric $\sin$/$\cos$/$\tan$ identities.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please see the figure below for an illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\epsilon-\epsilon\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta\right).$$
Thus, we need to prove that
$$\epsilon-\epsilon\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\theta\right)\leq\frac{16\epsilon\theta}{\pi}$$ or
$$1-\frac{1-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}\leq\frac{16\theta}{\pi}$$ or
$$\frac{\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}\leq\frac{8\theta}{\pi},$$
which is true because easy to show that even
$$\frac{\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}\leq\theta$$ 
is true for all $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Indeed, let $$f(\theta)=\theta-\frac{\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}.$$
Hence, $$f'(\theta)=1-\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta(1+\tan\theta)^2}=1-\frac{1}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2}\geq0.$$
Thus, $f(\theta)\geq f(0)=0$ and we are done!

Comment: Thanks so much, somehow did  not realize the horizontal distance to the edge is also $\epsilon$.  Apologies for the wrong question the first time round!

Comment: @John Smith You are welcome!